# Join a piecewise plot

Tags: plotting, interpolation

I wrote some code to get a piecewise plot which is displayed correctly. Now I'd like to join the various parts of the plot, using some kind of interpolation, to get a continuous chart even though it's actually a piecewise one.

Let me to give you an example. Assuming $f_1(2) = 3$ and $f_2(2) = 1$, how can I join the points $(2,3)$ and $(2,1)$ in the plot?

Comment: Should we assume that f1(3) and f2(1) are undefined?

Comment: How do I make a piecewise function not continue at 0 after I've set my limits? I'm trying to make a shape but when I set my bounds ie 0<=x<=4 for the equation 2x the line will continue at y=0

Comment: @abbie if you have a new question please post a separate question rather than answering old ones. Please remember to include the code you are using.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your questions is not that clear to me, but I guess you want to join the two piece wise parts with a vertical line. That would be `Exclusions`.

```
Plot[Piecewise[{{3, x < 2}, {1, x > 2}}], {x, -2, 5}, Exclusions -> None]
```

leads to

[image]